# Laravel 7 Saving Base64 Image Converted in Local Storage

Tags: laravel, image, base64, storage, image-scaling

So basically I have a front side app that makes a axios call to a backend api in Laravel 7. I'm sending a `base64` image string  and a the name the user give to it in an input text

The controller in the API I'm making should do the following:

1. get the data, create a new record in my mysql db with the name and the base64string
2. create 3 version of the image(thumbnail, mid and large)
3. add a watermark on the bottom right
4. create a new folder in storage
5. put the new images in the same folder

so basically at the end if I have 10 calls from the front, I should have 10 rows in my db and 10 folders in my storage with 3 images inside each one

points 1, and 4 are done

cannot figure how to save it with the 3 different dimensions..

this is my controller so far:

```
public function save(Request $request){
  $data = $request -> all();

  $creation = Creation::make($data); //saving record in db
  $creation->hash = '0000'.$work_name;
  // $creation ->tshirt_id = 1;
  $creation -> save();

  $work_name = $data['processing_name']; //name from input text
  $encoded_img = $data['image'];   //get the base64 img string

  $decoded_img = \base64_decode(\explode(',', $decoded_img)[1]); //decoding image
  
  $thumb = .5; //set the scaling ratio for large
  $mid = .8; //set the scaling ratio for large
  $large = 1.5; //set the scaling ratio for large

  $sizeInfo = getimagesizefromstring($decoded_img); //get width and height of image
  $original_width = $sizeInfo[0];
  $original_height = $sizeInfo[1]; 

  
  $largeWidth = $original_width * $large;//set the new width and height of image
  $largeHeight = $original_height * $large;

  $largeWidth = $original_width * $mid;//set the new width and height of image
  $largeHeight = $original_height * $mid;
  
  $largeWidth = $original_width * $thumb;//set the new width and height of image
  $largeHeight = $original_height * $thumb;


  $last_created = $creation -> id; //get the id of the last inserted record
  
  //new location setup in storage 
  $newFolder = Storage::makeDirectory('public/creations/'. $last_created .'_Images_' . $work_name);


  //NOW I NEED TO SAVE 3 VERSION OF THE IMAGE IN THIS FOLDER whith that sizes
```

The images are png with some transparency and I already try this way adding resampling:

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

//getting error on imagecreatetruecolor
```

Comment: Can you share what error it is you're getting?

Comment: And could you please avoid ALL CAPS titles.

Comment: this is the errore from the network on chrome :

"message": "Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\imagecreatetruecolor()",

Comment: and this is the code i tried:

 $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);

$image = imagecreatefrompng($encoded_img);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth,$thumbHeight, $original_width, $original_height);

Answer (score 0):

`imagecreatetruecolor()` is not a function defined by PHP, but I presume its a function of one of your controllers/services/models, therefore if you want to access it, you need to refer to it as a method, so `$this or $controller or $whatever ->imagecreatetruecolor(...)`, instead of calling it out of nowhere.

Comment: you should check   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php